# Combine two Tables with identical structure

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I got two tables which are identical where I am saving a question , surname and forename . One of it is for UK and one for US.Now I want to find out which person asked the most question. I tried out and find a solution for it :

```
SELECT QUESTION , SURNAME , FORENAME , Count(*) 
FROM table_UK 
    GROUP BY SURNAME,FORENAME 
        ORDER BY 1 
            DESC LIMIT 10
```

This also gives me the result I want but this is just for the UK table. I want to find out the top 10 most asked person.This means I have to combine the tables UK and US and then list them.I don't want TOP 10 from UK and Top 10 from US.They should be mixed together.

Now I found out the 'UNION' command to combine tables.So I tried it and executed this :

```
SELECT QUESTION , SURNAME , FORENAME , Count(*) 
    FROM table_UK 
        UNION 
            SELECT QUESTION , SURNAME , FORENAME , Count(*) 
                FROM table_US
                    GROUP BY SURNAME,FORENAME ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 10
```

But this gaves me wrong results.Somehow it is counting wrong. Someone got a Idea how I can get to a solution ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT SURNAME , FORENAME , Count(*) as RANK
        FROM table_UK 
    GROUP BY SURNAME , FORENAME 
    UNION 
    SELECT SURNAME , FORENAME , Count(*) as RANK
        FROM table_US
    GROUP BY SURNAME,FORENAME 
    ) as t
    ORDER BY t.RANK DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Missing `FROM` and alias for outer query, `COUNT()` goes in outer query. Use `UNION ALL`.